What does it mean "length_scale_bounds" in a RBF kernel from a gaussian process?
I'm studying gaussian emulation process, in particular the use of the RBF kernel and I'm not understanding the meaning of length_scale_bounds. Can one helps me?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
